# Using min() and max() functions with multiple strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a short CodingBat problem: given 2 strings, a and b, return a string of the form short+long+short, with the shorter string on the outside and the longer string on the inside.

Here is what I have:

```
def combo_string(a, b):
    short = min(a, b)
    long = max(a, b)
    return short + long + short
```

The idea: `min(a, b)` would return the shortest of the two strings and `max(a, b)` would return the longest of the two. However, this code works inconsistently.

`combo_string('a', 'bb')` returns `'abba'` (correct), but `combo_string('Hello', 'hi')` returns `'HellohiHello'` (incorrect and actually opposite of what I want).

Am I using the min() and max() functions incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hello` alphabetically precedes `hi` so it is the "minimum." What you want to do is use the `key` argument to specify that you want the minimum *length,* not the minimum *value.*

```
min(a, b, key=len)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the key function (which will be `len`). Otherwise, Python will sort lexicographically (alphabetically, basically), which is almost certainly not what you want:

```
def combo_string(a, b):
    short = min(a, b, key=len)
    long = max(a, b, key=len)
    return short + long + short
```

For example:

```
min('a', 'bb', key=len)
# 'a'
min('Hello', 'hi', key=len)
# 'hi'
```

Basically, instead of just using the `>` and `<` operator s for comparison (i.e. `a > b` or whatever), the `min` and `max` functions will use the result of the `key` function (i.e. `len(a) > len(b)` or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

> Am I using the min() and max() functions incorrectly?

Yep. Basically, your problem is that `max(a, b)` isn't exactly doing what you think it is. `max(a, b)` compares the string objects `a` and `b` themselves. Python implements comparisons between strings *not by the strings length*, but by their [lexicographical values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

This means that sometimes `max(a, b)` might happen to work, but not always. You need to tell Python to directly compare the lengths of the strings by using `len`.